# PuTTY working, Terminal SSH is not (with Private Key)

Tags: windows, ssh, terminal, centos, cmder

Setup a new server (on Rackspace), got it working in PuTTY/KiTTY.

When I run from terminal (Cmder), it asks me to enter a passphrase (which PuTTY doesn't), I hit "enter" (there is no passphrase), then it proceeds to ask me the user's password - defeating the purpose.

Any suggestions?

OS: Windows 7
Terminal: Cmder
Private Key: .ppk created from Puttygen
Server: Rackspace Centos 6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since putty works, I assume the server side is setup properly.

You need to convert the private key(ppk) used in putty. To do so,

1. Run

   `ssh -v user@yourhost`

from Cmder and check the debug output, you can see that its looking for keys in `C:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh` folder. first key should be `C:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh\id_rsa`.

2. Now run puttygen, on the menu select `Conversions->Import key`, import the ppk, then `Conversion->Export OpenSSH key` and save the exported key to the file mentioned in 1, `C:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh\id_rsa`.
3. Try ssh from Cmder again, should work now.

Comment: I can connect to my server using putty with my id_rsa.ppk but I cannot connect using cmder even after following the instructions above.

Comment: What does ssh -v user@yourhost show?

Comment: for me also it does not connect, message I got is => "debug1: Trying private key: .keys/.my-key
Load key ".keys/.my-key": invalid format"